# I want to convert XPath value like Z.12.s from Z12s using xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

Please any one help me on converting XPath value to dot (full stop) separated.

E.g:  Z12s to Z. 12.after 1st char need put dot and after 2 char dot then every 2 chars dot but not last value.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the length of the input string, you will need to use a recursive named template for this, such as:

```
<xsl:template name="split-string">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="length" select="1"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 1, $length)"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($string) > $length">
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="split-string">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring($string, $length + 1)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="length" select="2"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4HF

Comment: Thanks Michael...but we need to convert based on the xpath value from XML instead of entire XML

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what you mean by that. Please edit your question and show a [mcve].

Comment: I want to implement this code for converting only one field from input xml , instead of copying entire input and do conversion.

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what you mean by that either. Please edit your question and show a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

If your address can be over 90 characters, add more if's to the AddressDetail template according the pattern that is in the template.

```
    <xsl:template match="AddressDetails">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*">
          <xsl:with-param name="address" select="substring(Address, 1, 30)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:if test="string-length(Address) &gt; 30">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*">
            <xsl:with-param name="address" select="substring(Address, 31, 30)"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="string-length(Address) &gt; 60">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*">
            <xsl:with-param name="address" select="substring(Address, 61, 30)"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
      <!-- etc. -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Address">
      <xsl:param name="address"/>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$address"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```