# Split xml element based on size

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Given the following XML example file :

```
<root>
<UserList>
    <UserDetails>
        <Info1>
            <Info1_Id>AA</Info1_Id>
        </Info1>
        <Info2>
            <Info2_Id>BB</Info2_Id>
        </Info2>
    </UserDetails>
    <UserAddress>
        <State>Maharastra</State>
        <AddressDetails>
            <City>Mumbai</City>
            <Address>Andheri Kurla Road, Mumbai</Address>
        </AddressDetails>
    </UserAddress>
    <UserAddress>
        <State>Karnataka</State>
        <AddressDetails>
            <City>Bangalore</City>
            <Address>ITPL Bangalore</Address>
        </AddressDetails>
        <AddressDetails>
            <City>Bangalore</City>
            <Address>XYZ Services Ltd in Whitefield Main Road, Bangalore</Address>
        </AddressDetails>
    </UserAddress>
</UserList>
```

I want to perform an XSL transformation to split and duplicate the element if Address length is more then 30. If address length is more then 30, First element will contain first 30 characters and new(duplicated) element will contain next 30 characters, so on.

Expected output :

```
<root>
<UserList>
    <UserDetails>
        <Info1>
            <Info1_Id>AA</Info1_Id>
        </Info1>
        <Info2>
            <Info2_Id>BB</Info2_Id>
        </Info2>
    </UserDetails>
    <UserAddress>
        <State>Maharastra</State>
        <AddressDetails>
            <City>Mumbai</City>
            <Address>Andheri Kurla Road, Mumbai</Address>
        </AddressDetails>
    </UserAddress>
    <UserAddress>
        <State>Karnataka</State>
        <AddressDetails>
            <City>Bangalore</City>
            <Address>ITPL Bangalore</Address>
        </AddressDetails>
        <AddressDetails>
            <City>Bangalore</City>
            <Address>XYZ Services Ltd in Whitefield</Address>
        </AddressDetails>
        <AddressDetails>
            <City>Bangalore</City>
            <Address> Main Road, Bangalore</Address>
        </AddressDetails>
    </UserAddress>
</UserList>
```

How It can be achieved. Thanks in Advance for any help.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60522091/3016153

Comment: But How to create new new element and split the content between then?

Comment: Instead of `<xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 1, $length)"/>` do `<Address><xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 1, $length)"/></Address>` etc.

Comment: It does not generates expected output.
Link to input and expected output:  https://pasteboard.co/J5hu959.png

Comment: I suggest you try to implement it and if you run into a problem, post a new question with your attempt. Currently you are asking for someone to do your coding for you. I am not interested in doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only handle addresses up to 90 characters.  But, you can extend that by adding more if's to the AddressDetails template according to the pattern.

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:exslt ="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="exslt">
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


    <xsl:template match="AddressDetails">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*">
          <xsl:with-param name="address" select="substring(Address, 1, 30)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:if test="string-length(Address) &gt; 30">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*">
            <xsl:with-param name="address" select="substring(Address, 31, 30)"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="string-length(Address) &gt; 60">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*">
            <xsl:with-param name="address" select="substring(Address, 61, 30)"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
      <!-- etc. -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Address">
      <xsl:param name="address"/>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$address"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


  </xsl:stylesheet>
```