# XSL output substring differs // recursion doesn't call data

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, substring

I need to substring the following input but, with the iterative version (wrong data excluded!), the output of the third case is wrong. But the methods used are the same.

For the recursive version I tried a lot of ways, but it doesn't work any way..!

If someone could help me or tell me, why the output differs at the iterative way, i would be very thankful!

The iterative version is tested with the following data input

```
1: 1234 
2: 123456789012345678901234 
3: 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123
```

Output:

1: correct

```
1234
```

2: correct

```
12345678901234567890
1234
```

3: wrong

```
12345678901234567890
12345678901234567890**123**
123
```

```
<xsl:template match="reportId">
    <xsl:variable name="reportId" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($reportId) &gt; 21 and string-length($reportId) &lt; 40">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($reportId,1,20)" />
                <fo:block/>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($reportId,21)" />
                <fo:block/>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($reportId) &gt; 41 and string-length($reportId) &lt; 60">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($reportId,1,20)" />
                <fo:block/>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($reportId,21,40)" />
                <fo:block/>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($reportId,41)" />
                <fo:block/>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$reportId"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>
```

Iterative version

```
<xsl:template match="subId">
    <xsl:param name="prev"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$prev != ''">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($prev,1,20)" />
            </fo:block>
            <xsl:call-template name="subId">
                <xsl:with-param name="prev" select="substring($prev,21)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="reportId">
    <xsl:variable name="reportId" select="."/>
    <xsl:call-template name="subId">
        <xsl:with-param name="prev" select="$reportId"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Note that `&gt; 21` does not include 21 (and likewise for 41).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($reportId,21,40)" />
```

returns **40 characters** from the input string, starting at character #21. If you want to split your input into substrings of 20 characters, you should be using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($reportId,21,20)" />
```

---

Note that your code could be simplified to:

```
<xsl:template match="reportId"> 
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 20)" />
        <fo:block/>
    </fo:block>
    <xsl:if test="string-length(.) > 20">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 21, 20)" />
            <fo:block/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="string-length(.) > 40">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 41)" />
            <fo:block/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Even better, use a truly recursive template - see for example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60522091/3016153

Comment: Thank you soo much! :)